# Ambiguous tag [piston]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

[piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston) tag is used as a synonym of [django-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-piston), which became a problem because in Rust, we started having questions about the [Piston graphics crate](http://www.piston.rs/).

I want to create a [rust-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-piston) tag, but this makes [piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston) ambiguous and no longer a trivial synonym.

There are [28 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston) tagged with piston:

- There are [2 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston%20rust?mode=all) that use [piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston) and [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust)
- There are [23 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston%20django?mode=all) that use [piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston) and [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django).
- There is [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297125/basic-http-authentication-with-django-piston) that doesn't put [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django).
- There are 2 ([x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869530/how-do-i-force-git-to-think-a-file-is-unmerged), [y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267931/piston-git-support)) questions about [piston from ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/piston)

So I want to:

1. Create [rust-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-piston) tag
2. Maybe create [ruby-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-piston) tag
3. Edit piston info or remove it
4. If this is accepted, we must of course edit these questions' tags.

Comment: Perhaps `[django-piston]` is better than `[ruby-piston]`?

Comment: It should be possible to blacklist the `piston` tag to avoid the ambiguity reappearing in the future; although maybe just untagging all questions and wait for the roomba to remove it should be enough.

Comment: IIRC, blacklisting can only be done by developers. We can of course request it.

Comment: Should we blow the `[piston]`?

Comment: i say it would be better to untag everything from `[piston]` and sort accordingly to `[django-piston]` etc. and monitor the questions being submitted with the tag and retag accordingly and submit blacklist request, leaving the current tag there to be removed when the blacklist goes through then the tag can be removed, because if you remove it now then theres nothing stopping users with >1.5k recreating it

Comment: Looks like someone already removed the synonym

Comment: The [piston] is getting rusty. Get Ruby and Django to look at it?

Comment: @PeterHall Maybe there is a confusion, [tag:django-piston] already exist with 135 questions and I see no reason to change it. When I said maybe create [tag:ruby-piston], it's only because there are two questions about a tool write in ruby that it's called piston.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was completed.**

Here is the current status:

As @Stargateur said, [django-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-piston) already exists, so I've retagged 20+ [piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piston) questions left, because all of them were related to Django-Piston. This tag will be gone in 24 hours.

Looks like [rust-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-piston) and [ruby-piston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-piston) were created earlier.